# Issue with placing image next to submit form , next to each other

Tags: html, css, position, element

I have been trying to place image in class position-image
next to the form in class position-form. I have tried so many
different things display flex , float method nothing has worked
for me , the elements always get squeezed in the corner and
change shape even though I change width

```
 <div class ="submit-form">
<div class ="position-form">
  <form class ="form"action="https://formsubmit.co/jani.godojo@gmail.com" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="fname"placeholder="Enter your first 
    name"required>
    <input type="text" id="lname"placeholder="Enter your last name" 
     required>
    <input type="text" id="email"placeholder="Enter your email" 
    required>
    <textarea name ="text-inquiry" rows ="10" wrap ="hard" 
  placeholder="Write your inquiry here..."></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div> 
  <div class ="position-image"><img src="images/add.jpg" style 
 ="width:20%;"></div>
 </div>

   .submit-form {
    border-radius:2%;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 5%;
    display: flex;
    }
    input[type=text-inquiry], select {
    width: 30%;
    height:50%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid rgb(192, 192, 192);
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .form > textarea{
    width:30%;
    }
   .position-form{
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   align-content: flex-start;
   width:50%;}

  .position-image img{
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  width:50%;
  }
```

Comment: Here is my CSS code

Comment: .submit-form {
  border-radius:2%;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 5%;
  display: flex;
}

Comment: Is this all your css? Please add it directly to your question

Comment: Not all of it just what I have for the submit form section where is submit from on the left and picture on the right a

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, where should the elements be placed? The form with all inputs under each other and the image beside the form on the right side?

Comment: @Corrl ye that's precisely what I am after currently I have the inputs under each other but the image just wouldn't move next to them, and when it does the entire picture and the form resize

Comment: Somebody suggested to me to place it into the table tag but that didnt work either I am really lost with this what do I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you see the comments in the example, play around with it and just try to get used to flexbox. There are a lot of useful sites out there which explain it in depth like [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.submit-form {
  display: flex;  /*sets form and image next to each other*/  
  border-radius: 2%;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 5%;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /*> elements in form beneath each other */
}
```

```html
<div class="submit-form">
  <form class="form" action="https://formsubmit.co/jani.godojo@gmail.com" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="Enter your first 
    name" required>
    <input type="text" id="lname" placeholder="Enter your last name" required>
    <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required>
    <textarea name="text-inquiry" rows="10" wrap="hard" placeholder="Write your inquiry here..."></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

  <img src="images/add.jpg" style="width:20%;">
</div>
```

Comment: Ye I actually worked it out last night with flex box it is a great tool

Answer (score 0):

```
.flex-class{
 display:flex;
 align-content: center;
 justify-content: space-around;
 padding-bottom: 40px;
 }
 #column-residential{
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding:15px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color:#eeeeee;
   }
  #column-commercial{
   border-radius: 5px;
   padding:15px;
   width: 400px;
   background-color: #eeeeee;
```